# Parse 2D string array to 2D int array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm looking for a way to associate each row from this file(csv) and to take the monthly maximum(each column represents the month) associated with the store name. I can get the row maximums and column maximums but I do not know how to link each column maximum to their city name. Help please!

Here is the file:

```
Omaha,104,1218,418,216,438,618,274,234,510,538,740,540
Saint Louis,72,1006,392,686,626,670,204,286,236,344,394,930
Des Moines,116,1226,476,330,444,464,366,230,602,260,518,692
Chicago,408,948,80,472,626,290,372,282,488,456,376,580
Kansas City,308,1210,450,234,616,414,500,330,486,214,638,586
Austin,500,812,226,470,388,488,512,254,210,388,738,686
Houston,454,1086,430,616,356,534,218,420,494,382,476,846
New Orleans,304,1278,352,598,288,228,532,418,314,496,616,882
```

Here is my code so far:

```
File selectedFile = Utilities.selectFile("Type the file name: Ex:annualUnitsSold.csv        \n");
int numberRecords = Utilities.countLinesInFile(selectedFile);
String[][] records = Utilities.loadStringsFromFile(selectedFile, numberRecords);

System.out.println(columnCompare(records,1);
public static int columnCompare (String[][] array, int col)
{
    String report = "";
    int monthMax = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {
        if(monthMax < Integer.parseInt(array[row][col]))
        {   
            monthMax = Integer.parseInt(array[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return monthMax;
}
//NOTE: when i run this it works as long as i put the column number greater than zero.
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to find a way to associated the first column(cities) so that they are able to represent the monthly maximums out of every col. Example: column 1: 500;  but now how do i get it so it displays austin along with it?

Comment: The city name is in column 0, so when you find a maximum, remember also the associated city from array[row][0].

Comment: Thank you so much.  I don't know why I was confusing myself so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cities = new HashMap<>();
...
cities.put(city, columnCompare(...));
```

Comment: I can't use a hashmap for this assignment. Thanks though

Comment: You didn't mention constraints. What are they?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking up the values, you can look up the index:

```
int month = 1;
int store = columnCompare(records, month);
System.out.println(records[store, 0] + ": " + records[store, month]);
public static int columnCompare (String[][] array, int col)
{
    int rowMax = 0;
    int monthMax = -1;
    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
    {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(array[row][col]);
        if(monthMax < val)
        {
            rowMax = row;
            monthMax = val;
        }
    }
    return rowMax;
}
```